# .HEIC file to .JPG not identified by PIL.Image

Tags: python-imaging-library, jpeg, heic

I am running a script to extract the EXIF data from a list of images in a folder that are imported from an iPhone using Python's `pillow`:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(path)
```

But before anything, some of the pictures need to be converted from iOS' format `.HEIC` to `.jpg`. I successfully managed to do so but when I try to open the image that was converted I get the following:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '.../pictures/IMG_4294.jpg'
```

See this image comparing the info of two files. The one on the left was converted from `.HEIC` to `.jpg` and doesn't work. The one on the right is originally a `.jpg` and works just fine.

Any thoughts on how I can solve this?

[image]